# CodeIgniter cache folder in full every 2 days

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have CodeIgniter

```
CI_VERSION = '3.1.5'
```

and i have this into confing.php

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'        = the name you want for the cookie
| 'sess_expiration'         = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'sess_expire_on_close'    = Whether to cause the session to expire automatically
|   when the browser window is closed
| 'sess_encrypt_cookie'     = Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'sess_use_database'       = Whether to save the session data to a database
| 'sess_table_name'         = The name of the session database table
| 'sess_match_ip'           = Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data
| 'sess_match_useragent'    = Whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data
| 'sess_time_to_update'     = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3000;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache1/';
/*
```

so as you see above, the ci_session is stored into the chache1 folder
i have to change the path to the sess_save_path every 2 days, because it become full ( about 900MB to 1 GB ) and the site will not work due to full disk ( as i got this error message in log file )
i tried to search a solution , and got nothing .
so what i have to do to auto remove the cache folder or its files into it ?
or is there any chance to cron job, or clean this folder every day ?
know that when i change the sess_path, all of my clients had to login again
thanks a lot, and hope to get any solution here :)

i tried to search for a solution but unlucky with it

Comment: Have you thought about using the database driver? https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#database-driver

Comment: sess_expiration never expires.  Why not?

Comment: @James yes i tried using database , i got error and the site not working at all ..
i already have  Table: ci_sessions into my database, but it store nothing 
thanks for your reply

Comment: @James so i have to set it to expire ? like this : 
$config['sess_expiration']= 18000; //5 hours ?

Comment: Getting an error message doesn't mean you shouldn't use the database, but that you did something wrong.  :)  What was the error?  You don't have to expire the sessions if you don't want to, but it's generally a good practice.  Yes, that's how you would do it.

Comment: @James, thanks :) 
i did it and there is no error in my site and the ci_sessions is stored successfully into my database . after 10 hours , the ci_sessions table have 1 Million rows and t he site stopped working , i empty the table ci_sessions and the site returned to work 
so i have to empty this table every day ?
thanks for your reply

Comment: I would set `sess_match_ip` to true, and make sure to add the primary key to the table `ALTER TABLE ci_sessions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, ip_address);`.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
#1068 - Multiple primary key defined
i can't set 2 primary key :)

Comment: Then you've already set the primary key on the table, and just need to set the `$config` variable.